# Is there a way to get frame childs reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, tkinter-entry

I wrote a GUI that is working fine, it's supposed to get some information from a file and to show me on entries, and base on how many lines of info are present, it will generate same many entries.

The problem on this code is: I want to let me to change some values and to save them back on file and I do not know how to take that entry.get() from all entries on the frame. If I try to get a reference on it I will get back just the last entry changes printed.

```py
def DataShow(self):
    # Import dictionary after the settings file was read
    from res.lib.Settings import app_settings

    # Make local frame
    frame = ScrolledFrameVertical(self, width=353)
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill="y", side="top")

    Button(frame, text="Save", command=lambda:save()).pack(fill="x", side="top")

    # Create entrys base on dictionary data and info
    for data, info in app_settings.items():
        d = Settings.Entry(frame, data, 20, info, 31)

    def save():
        print(d.get())
```

And is look like that:
[image: And is look like that]

Comment: U can try to add the `textvariable` when youc reate the entry widget for save the entry value and get it back when u want see [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) for more infos

Comment: Your problem is to get all the childrens of a widget? (Frame in that case)

Comment: From `Settings.Entry(frame, data, 20, info, 31)` I return just the entry. They are generated and I do not know how to get them values... I still try with that `textvariable`

Comment: Can you use either `data` or `info` as key to save the reference of the `Entry` in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all children of a widget with `.winfo_children()`.

```
def save():
    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        print(child.get())
```

Comment: Was not so easy to understand this, but I played with it and that `.winfo_children()` was my solution. Thanks a lot.